# Mathematical Expression Using Lists

Tags: python, list, foreach

I realize that the output is simply the base_q - (base_q * q_growth_rates), but I'm having trouble coding the multiplication and subtraction of the lists.

#Build a list named quantities to mimic the output shown below

#Using base_q and q_growth_rates generate the following list

this is what I have

```
base_q = 100
q_growth_rates = [-0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.09999999999999998, 0.2]

quantities = []
for num in q_growth_rates: 
   base_q - (base_q * num)
```

This is the list it is supposed to generate after

```
print (quantities)
[80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 110.0, 120.0]
```

Comment: Please note that `*` has higher precedence than `-` so the extra parens in `base_q - (base_q * num)` are unnecessary.

Comment: Also that `base_q - base_q * num` is equivalent to `base_q * (1 - num)`.

Comment: @Chris that only provides one output.

Comment: I'm not suggesting using just that code, but simply a few ways to rewrite that one expression.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to append each result to quantities.

```
quantities.append(base_q - (base_q * num))
```

Comment: Or replace the loop with a listcomp: `quantities = [base_q - base_q * num for num in q_growth_rates]`

Comment: @ShadowRanger It ends up printing the values backward. For example, where 120.0 should be printed last, it is printed first.

Comment: The first growth rate is - 0.2. - 0.2 * 100 is - 20. 100 - ( - 20) is 100 + 20 which is 120 only.

Comment: @Saige: It printed the values in the order they were generated. If you want it in the opposite order, either replace the `-` with a `+` (for this specific case, it will reverse the values, and it's possible you made a math error relative to what you intended that this would fix) or run over `reversed(q_growth_rates)` (to actually reverse the input you're running against, so as to get the output reversed as well).